# set variables terminal os x

Tags: macos, terminal

really stumped with this.

i want to set a few variables for a script (paths)

according to everything i've found this should work but it doesn't;

```
SRC=/Volumes/MP_JUBBLER/testing/src/
SRC=/Volumes/MP_JUBBLER/testing/src/: Command not found.
echo $SRC
[MP-jynkBase:~] dan% echo $SRC
SRC: Undefined variable.
```

been bugging me for while!

many thanks, Dan.

Comment: Which shell are you using? `echo $SHELL` should tell you. I'm running BASH on Snow Leopard, and able to set variables the way you are trying to.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a Linux guy, but that looks like a *(t)csh* prompt to me instead of *bash* (which syntax you're trying to use).

In csh world variables can be set with

`setenv SRC "/Volumes/MP_JUBBLER/testing/src/"`

In Bash you could do:

`export SRC="/Volumes/MP_JUBBLER/testing/src/"`

(you need do this, because "normal" `x=y` assignments are cleared when the script stops running)

Comment: I think you're right. It looks like a csh error message, too.

Comment: yeh its (t)csh and that works. Des that then set the varibale forever or just for this session? thanks, Dan.